# How can I data bind a model’s properties in the FileSelect component directly?

Tags: telerik, telerik-blazor

I want to extend the ‘[Telerik ListView Editing](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/listview/editing)’ example with a FileSelect component. In the UI you should be able to see the file name and ID immediately.

When I press 'Add' directly it should say:

```
Employee: @context.Id <br />
Name: @context.Name in team: @context.Team
FileId…
FileName.....
```

The other components use:

```
<TelerikTextBox @bind-Value="@context.Name" /><br />
<TelerikDropDownList Data="@Teams" @bind-Value="@context.Team" />
```